# Is browser extension using 3rd party API legal here?

Tags: support

Suppose I want to write a browser extension for Stack Overflow, which would introduce some new feature. But in order to do that, it would use my webserver for storing data (I mean some actions of users with this extension would be reported to external API).

The question: can I announce here, on Meta (or on stackapps), such an extension for others to download?

SOUP, SOX and other extensions seem to be full-client, or maybe using requests to SO servers.

Comment: You'd likely fare better on Stack Apps than here, but so long as it [fits within the ToS of the API](http://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use) and isn't blatantly stealing PII, I'm not sure anyone would have a problem with it.  Of course, the logical question would be, why do you need to store the data yourself?

Comment: @Makoto Maybe I don't get it, but the link you posted is about SE API, which I wouldn't use at all. As of why store myself, that's because the feature I want to make requires saving some info.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you'd want to store data externally, if it's a browser extension.  HTML5 offers plenty of options for offline storage.  What are you developing?

Comment: @Makoto I think that since [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106717) is totally opt-in feature, it can be done with a userscript.

Comment: I am one of the authors of SOX and we use GM_ storage functions to retain user settings so everything is stored locally.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ I know, that's why my question exists.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is similar to the script [Stack Exchange Chat Status - adding Hangouts-style avatars to chat](https://stackapps.com/q/6704), which was announced on Stack Apps last year, and did not cause any problems as far as I know.

If some users decide to report some of their SE activity to a 3rd party server, it's their business.

I don't think that announcing an extension here on Meta would work well; it's better to post on Stack Apps and as an answer to [Meta.SE proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106717) which the extension implements.